# Can't use DjangoRestFramework with Requests because of self-signed-cert in chain

Tags: python, django, ssl, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I've got 2 Django applications that I need to be talking to each other via the DjangoRestFramework. The apps live on Windows Servers that run Apache to serve the data.

They live on separate boxes within my infrastructure and here we use a self-signed cert for internal things because that's a requirement.

When I try to make the request, it's upset with the self-signed-certificate in the chain and doesn't finish the request.

I made a little utility function that reaches out to the API:

```
def get_future_assignments(user_id):
    """gets a users data from the API

    Arguments:
        user_id {int} -- user_id for a User
    """
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }
    api_app = settings.MY_API
    api_model = 'api_endpoint/'
    api_query = '?user_id='+str(user_id)
    json_response = requests.get(
        api_app+api_model+api_query,
        headers=headers,
        verify=False
    )
    return json.loads(json_response.content)
```

using `verify=False` allows the endpoint to run and give back appropriate data. If I remove that it will fail saying there is a `self-signed-cert in the chain` and not finish the call.

The overall layout is like this:

Server1: https - self-signed (`server1.cer` (making the call))

Server2: https - self-signed (`server2.cer` (api lives on this server))

I have the root certificate we install on browsers and such within the organization (`rootcert.cer`).

I'm not too well versed in certs so I am not sure which ones I should be sending across with the request.

I know there is a `cert` argument that can be used in requests - but I'm unsure what to put in there.

I'm pretty sure I would need something like this:

```
json_response = requests.get(
    api_app+api_model+api_query,
    headers=headers,
    cert= our_cert, # not sure which cert this would be...
    key= our_root_ca # do I need this? Not sure...
)
```

But any help from people who know certs a bit better is appreciated!

Comment: the cert there is usually a pem buffer, this is likely what you need for this to work also.

Comment: So I would need to convert the `.cer` files to `.pem` ?

Comment: Also @bryan60 - do you know if there's a way to Mock this locally to get the same issues? If I run these two apps on `localhost` it doesn't cause issues (same server); but in the wild - this issue presents itself.

Comment: not totally sure, I did this in node with same self signed cert in chain issue.  adding the cert to the request fixed it.  As for mocking, you'd generally try to debug this in a staging type environment that almost exactly mirrors the prod infrastrucutre.  Easy enough with AWS like services where you can start a couple boxes for an hour or two and pay very little.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately we don't really have a staging environment - despite my cries to management that we need one. Stinks, because situations like this would be totally prevented. I've been looking heavily at Docker. Management seems on board with it - and then we could have 'staging', be local and identical to production and help us eliminate these issues.

Comment: I’ve never used docker in this manner, but I know that multiple boxes can be simulated with VMs, so it could work out